# What's the meaning of ブチブチ?

Tags: words

I'm having some trouble to find the meaning of this word. I already saw this 2 times in a game and I can't find the meaning in any dictionary that I use.

Examples:

> あやせ：「そうなると私のことなんか放っておいて…」
>
> 京介：  ブチブチと文句を言ってくる…んだけど、あれ？なんだか言葉の切れ味が鈍いような…

and...

> 加奈子：「イイエ、ナンデモ」
>
> あやせ：加奈子はそのあともブチブチと何か言っていたけど…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From context (such as ブチブチと**文句を**言って), it looks like `ブチブチ` has the same meaning as `ブツブツ`, which is onomatopoeia that corresponds fairly well to *grumble, grumble*, as when dissatisfied or complaining.  See [sense five for ブツブツ in the Progressive J-E](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&stype=0&dtype=3&p=%E3%81%B6%E3%81%A4%E3%81%B6%E3%81%A4) for examples, or look up `ブツブツ` in your favorite dictionary.

I also found [Google results](https://www.google.com/search?hl=ja&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=%E3%83%96%E3%83%84%E3%83%96%E3%83%84%E3%80%80%E3%83%96%E3%83%81%E3%83%96%E3%83%81&=&=&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1) with `ブツブツ` and `ブチブチ` together, which seems to confirm that they're variations on the same thing.

Comment: Here's a little more [discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10745162#10745162) with comments by Chocolate, and [some more comments](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10745873#10745873) by marasai.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that ブチブチ is a variation on ブツブツ, but rather a softening of プチプチ. プチプチ is a crackling noise. Softening it to ブチブチ suggests a more annoying, thick type of complaint in this case, which may contain more information/emotion than one would like. A complaint that is プチプチ could be ignored as background noise, but a ブチブチ complaint suggests that the person is laying it on thick and is truly annoying. Of course, describing a complaint with ブチブチ is derogatory in the sense that speech is described as an annoying sound, rather than words.

Answer (score 0):

Buchi is a old showa slang for actions like running away without saying a word, being careless or just not giving a damn fuck? also could be interpreted like sleeping on the switch, when someone sleep in the classroom, ignore a phone call or skive to work.

Comment: `Buchi is a old showa slang for actions like running away...` <- 「ブッチ」のことですか？　http://zokugo-dict.com/28hu/bucchi.htm